# Able to access property in User Profile properties but not anymore?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm using the following code to update a custom property in SharePoint User Profile .

The code was working fine so far but now when i debug it can't find the custom property for some reason.

```
string requesterLoginName = currentListItem["RequesterLoginName"].ToString();
                        double workDaysRequested = Convert.ToDouble(currentListItem["WorkDaysRequested"]);

                        PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
                        PersonProperties requesterProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(requesterLoginName);
                        clientContext.Load(requesterProperties);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        string currentLeaveDays = "";

                        // Convert entry to HTML.
                        foreach (var property in requesterProperties.UserProfileProperties)
                        {
                            if (property.Key == "LeaveDays")
                            {
                                currentLeaveDays = property.Value;

                            }

                        }
```

The "LeaveDays" custom property is existent and was working fine. Now i am not able to find it with debugging. Has anything changed with any updates on SharePoint Online?

Comment: Try to update one of the OOTB properties. If that works, could be so issue with the tenant. Raise a ticket with ms support , probably they might be able to help out.